# Loop over "define" values

Tags: arduino, hex, rgb, led

I have got RGB colors (HEX) in many #define values. I would like to loop over every of this color - I mean: first color is displayed - delay(1000) - second color - delay(1000) - third one etc.
Is it possible to do that with so many #define 's? And how to do that...

```
   #define AQUA "#00ffff"
   #define AZURE "#f0ffff"
   #define BEIGE "#f5f5dc"
   #define BLACK "#000000"
   #define BLUE "#0000ff"
   #define BROWN "#a52a2a"
   #define CYAN "#00ffff"
   #define DARKBLUE "#00008b"
   #define DARKCYAN "#008b8b"
   #define DARKGREY "#a9a9a9"
   #define DARKGREEN "#006400"
   #define DARKKHAKI "#bdb76b"
   #define DARKMAGENTA "#8b008b"
   #define DARKOLIVEGREEN "#556b2f"
   #define DARKORANGE "#ff8c00"
   #define DARKORCHID "#9932cc"
   #define DARKRED "#8b0000"
   #define DARKSALMON "#e9967a"
   #define DARKVIOLET "#9400d3"
   #define FUCHSIA "#ff00ff"
   #define GOLD "#ffd700"
   #define GREEN "#008000"
   #define KHAKI "#f0e68c"
   #define LIGHTBLUE "#add8e6"
   #define LIGHTCYAN "#e0ffff"
   #define LIGHTGREEN "#90ee90"
   #define LIGHTGREY "#d3d3d3"
   #define LIGHTPINK "#ffb6c1"
   #define LIGHTYELLOW "#ffffe0"
   #define LIME "#00ff00"
   #define MAGENTA "#ff00ff"
   #define MAROON "#800000"
   #define NAVY "#000080"
   #define OLIVE "#808000"
   #define ORANGE "#ffa500"
   #define PINK "#ffc0cb"
   #define PURPLE "#800080"
   #define VIOLET "#800080"
   #define RED "#ff0000"
   #define SILVER "#c0c0c0"
   #define WHITE "#ffffff"
   #define YELLOW "#ffff00"

int redPin = 9;
int greenPin = 10;
int bluePin = 11;


void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  String hexstring = AQUA;
    long number = (long) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);
    int r = number >> 16;
    int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
    int b = number & 0xFF;

setColor(r,g,b);

Serial.print("red is ");
Serial.println(r);
Serial.print("green is ");
Serial.println(g);
Serial.print("blue is ");
Serial.println(b);


}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue)
{
analogWrite(redPin, red);
analogWrite(greenPin, green);
analogWrite(bluePin, blue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it with *any* number of defines. Create an array with the values you want and then iterate over that.

```
char *colorarray[] = {AQUA, AZURE, ...};
```

Also, you should consider storing the colors as hexadecimal values instead of strings since they will take up less space.